# How can I check for a value in a Java Enumeration?

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to figure out how to use enumerations in Java, and I don't get how to do this:

```
public enum animalSounds {
    CAT("meow"),
    DOG("Woof"),
    PIG("Oink"),

    public final String animalName;

    animalSounds(String noise) {
        this.animalName = noise
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do, is pass in a string, and see if that string exists in the set of enumerables. So, I would pass in "Oink" and get back PIG, but if I pass in "Chirp", I would get some sort of error, as there is not enumeration value with "Chirp".

Comment: It looks like a drive-by down-vote of every answer, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enum is not the best thing to do for what you are trying to do but you could  try

```
private animalSounds getAnimal(String noise) {
    for(animalSounds a : animalSounds.values())
    {
        if(a.animalName.equals(noise))
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: +1 "Item 60: Favor the use of standard exceptions"—[Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Answer (score 1):

For a few, iterate through the `values()`; for many, create a `Map<String, AnimalSounds>`, as suggested [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9).

Answer (score 0):

Use the values() method - and iterate through the different types, doing your logic.